# Why doesn't my CSS style sheet link to my HTML template?

Tags: html, css, django, html-templates

One of my HTML templates that extends the `layout.html` template has a CSS file linked to it but when I try to style the HTML content through the CSS file, nothing happens even after reloading. There is already a CSS file linked to the `layout.html` file but that does not style the page either.

How do I make the `style.css` file style the `new.html` file (the page that should be styled)? Or should I make a new CSS file to style the `new.html` file?

layout.html:

```
{% load static %}

<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% block style %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

new.html:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block title %}
New Entry
{% endblock %}

{% block style %}
<link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/new.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<form action="">
    <input type="text" name="title" class="title" placeholder="Title">
    <textarea name="content" class="content" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Enter Content"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="save">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

style.css:

```
/* styling for the layout page */
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: white;
}

code {
    white-space: pre;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

textarea {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 80%;
}

.main {
    padding: 10px;
}

.search {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar h2 {
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: red;
}

/* attempt to style new.html */

.title {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

new.css:

```
.title {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.content {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Check if you defined static files config in settings.py properly or not.

Comment: How do you define static files?

Comment: Put your settings file Code

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/ I found this website about statci files and the steps were already done

Comment: Can you share your static folder structure or project structure if possible, and settings for static files in settings.py if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some time css file linked properly but it can't update, just try to update your css file using `?{% now "U" %}` at the end of `href` like

```
<link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/new.css' %}?{% now "U" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I was face same problem and I use update method that's worked

Comment: I fixed it by going into the page source then clicking into the link for the CSS file and reloading the CSS file then going back to the original page and reloading that and it works.

Comment: This worked as well though.